# Powershell. Select values from txt file and form list

Tags: powershell

I have txt file with data like this:

```
 PC:DELL:2018
 PC:HP:2016
 PC:HP:2016
 PC:DELL:2020
```

Would like parse it to:

```
 PC:DELL:2018,2020
 PC:HP:2016
```

Need to delete duplicate lines and append year for each unique manufacturer (HP,DELL), if there are more than one pair manufacturer:year.

Thanks.

Update.

Advice that was given here earlier:

```
Start by parsing each line and create corresponding objects with two properties each:

$objects = Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt |ForEach-Object {
  $parts = $_.Split(':')
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Manufacturer = $parts[0]
    Model = $parts[1]
  }
}

Now you can use Group-Object to group the objects by common Manufacturer:

$groups = $objects |Group-Object Manufacturer

And finally we can construct the desired output string based on the resulting groups:

$groups |ForEach-Object {
  # Extract the model numbers from the objects in each group, join into a single string 
  $models = $_.Group.Model -join ', '
  # Concatenate with the manufacturers name
  '{0}:{1}' -f $_.Name,$models
}
```

It works. At the beginning(to simplify) I asked for task where two "words" in each line and got that solution from member (Thanks Mathias R. Jessen). But in real case more than two.

I do not know if solution with "Group-Object" can be applied in case if there are three words or more. But idea was great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a similar solution works here, as well.

For example:

```
$values = Import-Csv -Path .\path\to\file.txt -Delimiter ':' -Header 'Type', 'Manufacturer', 'Year'

$groups = $values | Group-Object -Property 'Type','Manufacturer'

$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $typeMfg = $_.Name -replace ', ', ':'
    $years = ($_.Group.Year | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ','
    "{0}:{1}" -f $typeMfg, $years
}
```